# nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]] couldn't find "libvideoeditor_jni.so"

Tags: android

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.miimobileapp.miivdo-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]] couldn't find "libvideoeditor_jni.so"

Answer (score 4):

please try as below gradle settings:

```
gradle.properties:
android.useDeprecatedNdk=true

build.gradle
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "armeabi"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

gradle.properties:

```
android.useDeprecatedNdk=false
```

build.gradle:

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "armeabi"
        }
    }
}
```